# Low current to HS gate drive in DRV8825 typical application diagram

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, stepper-motor, texas-instruments

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkcNil.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The typical application diagram in the DRV8825 stepper driver datasheet includes a 1MOhm resistor from VM(the motor voltage) to VCP(which is internally connected to the HS gate drive. This resistor forms a parallel RC circuit with a 0.1uF capacitor.

My understanding of this section of the circuit would be that once the capacitor is charged, the bulk of the current would be flowing through the 1 MOhm resistor, and therefore would be very low due to the high resistance. My question is basically this-Why is this resistor included, when it means that the HS gate drive has a very low current flowing through it?

Another confusing element is that the Pololu breakout boards for these chips do not include the resistor, they just include the capacitor.

Comment: We have a built in circuit editor here that is quite handy in augmenting questions

Answer (score 1):

VCP is the power supply for the high side gates and which is generated from a charge pump.  It is a voltage higher than VM sufficient so that the high side MOSFET gates can turn on.

The resistor most likely ensures that the capacitor will be discharged (VCP to zero) when power is removed and re-energized so that the high side FET power supply is voltage during power up when the internal circuitry is in an undefined state.